# Is there someway to get reference to another application's window from your app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I'm working on a experimental project and I'm wondering if you can open an external application and have a reference to its window.

If I use NSWorkspace to launch an application like TextEdit, is there any way to get information about TextEdit's window from my application? And then be able to manipulate it.

What I mean by manipulate, is to be able to change style masks, change the title, or remove the drop shadow of the window. Stuff like that.

Comment: Manipulate a TextEdit window in what manner?  If you are talking about sending a text string or more to a TextEdit document, you can use AppleScript to create a new document with strings of your choice.

Comment: @ElTomato, Manipulate like change the style masks, the title, toggle whether it can close or be hidden; stuff like that. Would AppleScript be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is by using:

```
AXUIElementRef
```

An example might be wanting to get `CGWindowID` of a `Window Role` accessibility object:

```
extern "C" AXError _AXUIElementGetWindow(AXUIElementRef, CGWindowID* out);
```

This would enable the ability to retrieve the window info by means of the Accessibility API.

More informtion: [AXUIElement Header Reference](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html)